# why MyActivity wait GoogleApiClient Callbacks result before it go to next activity?

Tags: android, callback

i have:

```
            GoogleApiClientUtility googleApiClientUtility = new GoogleApiClientUtility(
                app.getGoogleApiClient(),
                new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                        try { sleep(10000); }
                        catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                        Log.e("GoogleApiClient: %s", "onConnected");
                        app.getGoogleApiClient().unregisterConnectionCallbacks(this);
                    }
                }
        );
        Log.e("GoogleApiClient: %s", "Connect");
        googleApiClientUtility.connect();

        Log.e("destination: %s", "main actvity");
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        this.finish();
```

my understanding of that code, it will pass through and go to MainActivity class directly.

but why when i compile it, it wait 10 secs before it goes to Main activity class

and even more strange in my log cat, it show my log as follow:

```
GoogleApiClient: Connect
destination: main actvity <-- it should go to main activity here
... wait 10 secs....
GoogleApiClient: onConnected;

then after that it goes to main activity...
```

anyone can explain why?
and how if i want to let user go to another activity without waiting the onConnected callbacks?

Comment: Remove the sleep

Comment: i use the sleep to simulate waiting time, is it really because of that?

Comment: You explicitly made the Activity wait for 10 seconds, yes

Comment: yes, i want it go to main activity, without waiting callback result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onConnected` is not called in a guaranteed order, as it's a callback. It could print its logs before or after the destination log message.

It waits because you're explicitly sleeping the MainActivity thread, which can cause the application to crash with ANR (Application Not Responding)

If you want to wait for the connection, this is how you do it

```
   GoogleApiClientUtility googleApiClientUtility = new GoogleApiClientUtility(
            app.getGoogleApiClient(),
            new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                    Log.e("GoogleApiClient: %s", "onConnected");
                    // app.getGoogleApiClient().unregisterConnectionCallbacks(this);
                    Log.e("destination: %s", "main actvity");
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    SplashActivity.this.finish();
                }
            }
    );
```

Otherwise, it's not clear why you need to simulate time passing.

You should actually use `unregisterConnectionCallbacks` during the `onStop` method of the Activity.

Comment: no, i dont want to wait the connection, i want it to flow through Main activity, while callback still running as well

Comment: Okay, then just remove the sleep from the callback

Comment: I use sleep to simulate waiting time, so i can see if it go to next activity before the callback done.

Comment: You're finishing the Activity, so I think the callback will be killed

Comment: yes, that's just a quick snippet of the code, so the actual code is not like that - 
ok,, you're right, seems like: sleep make the whole app sleep, i thought it only sleep on 1 particular thread

thanks, i think i got the answer - I mark this answer, based on your comments!

Comment: It is sleeping a particular thread. The callback happens on the UI thread. You would need to have a sleep within the GoogleApiClient code for what you want to work